# Entity Framework Core + Spatial Data is Raising SRID not vaild error

Tags: sql-server, geospatial, spatial, ef-core-2.2, asp-net-core-spa-services

I'm getting the following error:

> ERROR:
>   SqlException: .NET Framework error during routine execution or user-defined aggregate 'geography':
>   System.ArgumentException: 24204: spatial reference identifier (SRID) is not valid. The specified SRID must match one of the supported SRIDs shown in the sys.spatial_reference_systems catalog view.

This error is raised when I'm trying to save to SQL DB a point created like this

```
new Point(it.Lat, it.Lng)
```

After that I'v tried to use a `GeometryFactory` like this one:

```
    public static class GeometryHelper
    {
        public static IGeometryFactory GeometryFactory { get; set; }
            = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory();
    }
...
    geometryFactory.CreatePoint(new Coordinate(it.Lat, it.Lng))
```

And nothing.

Also tried setting a specific SRID:

```
    public static class GeometryHelper
    {
        public static IGeometryFactory GeometryFactory { get; set; }
            = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(4326);
    }
```

But then get this error:

> SqlException: .NET Framework error during routine execution or user-defined aggregate 'geography':
>   System.FormatException: One of the identified elements has an invalid format.
>   System.FormatException:

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solved a few minutes after posting the question. About the first error, the right way of solving it is doing what is in the question: Creating a geometry factory and use 4326 as SRID. You must check that the SRID you use is in the database table (`sys.spatial_reference_systems catalog view`). Apparently `4326` is a standard one as it is in the Microsft documentation.

```
    public static class GeometryHelper
    {
        public static IGeometryFactory GeometryFactory { get; set; }
            = NtsGeometryServices.Instance.CreateGeometryFactory(4326);
    }
```

The second error was related to the mapping between points and lat-lng objects.

> Longitude and Latitude
>   Coordinates in NTS are in terms of X and Y values. To represent longitude and latitude, use X for longitude and Y for latitude. Note that this is backwards from the latitude, longitude format in which you typically see these values.

Reference: [Spatial in Ef Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/spatial)

Comment: 4326 (often referred to EPSG:4326) is WGS84, which is the most common coordinate system used today. If you don't associate spatial objects with a coordinate system (spatial reference), then the software (in this case DB) will have no idea how to process the coordinates.

Answer (score 5):

I ran into this issue too. This is how i ended up solving it.

```
new Point(geoLocation.Longitude, geoLocation.Latitude) { SRID = 4326 }
```

Instead of creating and factory and creating a point i just assigned the SRID while creating the new Point instance.